# DataProvider' article example works but issues TypeError: Error #1009 at the same time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Reading up on `DataProvider` [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fce.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fb3)

The second code example that displays the data of a selected item, from the list, inside the `TextArea`.
The article's code, while does what it suppose to do, gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at fl.controls::TextArea/drawLayout()   at
>   fl.controls::TextArea/draw()  at
>   fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to also have the `TextArea` control inside my library.